# Ошибка MailKit.Security.SslHandshakeException C#

Tags: c#, .net, imap, windows-service, mailkit

Есть служба, которая мониторит почту, в случае когда приходит письмо, получает вложения и дальше с ними работает. Во время разработки и тестирования на локальном ПК проблем нет, при установки службы на сервер получаю ниже описанную ошибку:

> [15.05.2018 12:58:01.559]
>   [MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapClient+d__81.MoveNext()]
>   MailKit.Security.SslHandshakeException: An error occurred while
>   attempting to establish an SSL or TLS connection.
>
> One possibility is that you are trying to connect to a port which does
>   not support SSL/TLS.
>
> The other possibility is that the SSL certificate presented by the
>   server is not trusted by the system for one or more of the following
>   reasons:
>   1. The server is using a self-signed certificate which cannot be verified.
>   2. The local system is missing a Root or Intermediate certificate needed to verify the server's certificate.
>   3. The certificate presented by the server is expired or invalid.
>
> See
>   https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#InvalidSslCertificate
>   for possible solutions. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to write
>   data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly
>   closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An
>   existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   size, SocketFlags socketFlags)    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size)    at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[]
>   incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst,
>   Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
>   lazyResult)    at
>   MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapClient.d__81.MoveNext()    --- End
>   of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapClient.d__81.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapClient.Connect(String host, Int32
>   port, SecureSocketOptions options, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at EDIService1CConvert.Watcher.ConnectIMAP(),
>   имя метода - ConnectIMAP

Метод ConnectIMAP :

```
private void ConnectIMAP()
{
    try
    {
        using (CancellationTokenSource IMAPWatcherCancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            ImapClient client = new ImapClient();

            client.Connected += Client_Connected;

            client.Authenticated += Client_Authenticated;


            client.Connect(mailServer, mailPort, isSSL);
            client.Authenticate(userMailLogin, userMailPassword);
            //Директория на почтовом сервере
            IMailFolder inbox = client.Inbox;

            inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);

            inbox.CountChanged += Inbox_CountChanged;

            client.IdleAsync(IMAPWatcherCancelToken.Token);
            Log.Write(null, "IMAPWatcher запущен.", 1);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Write(ex, "ConnectIMAP", 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Там ведь все написано в ошибке:  1. The server is using a self-signed certificate which cannot be verified. 2. The local system is missing a Root or Intermediate certificate needed to verify the server's certificate. 3. The certificate presented by the server is expired or invalid.

Comment: @Zergatul это типо варианты из за чего может быть. Если я правильно понял все это касается удаленного сервера а не того с которого запуск идет. Когда запускаю службу на своей локально машине - все ок.

Comment: Возможно кто то перехватывает соединение и подменяет сертификат? Или на сервере нет нужного корневого сертификата

Comment: Операционная система должна поддерживать нужный TLS, убедитесь что у вас операционка обновлена и поддерживает TLS 1.2

Answer (score 0):

Тут есть возможные решения, но они не идеальны
[страница гитхаба](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/issues/735)

Вот одно из них:

```
 using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            client.CheckCertificateRevocation = false;
            await client.ConnectAsync("smtp.yandex.ru", 465, SecureSocketOptions.Auto);
```

Comment: вы предлагаете сознательно устроить дыру в безопасности клиента, это надо объяснять.

Answer (score 0):

Often private servers are configured for old versions of TLS/SSL for backward compatibility.
Specify which protocol version the server uses and explicitly set the version at the client.

```
ImapClient client = new ImapClient();

//set Tls 1.0 
client.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls;

client.Connect(mailServer, mailPort, isSSL);
client.Authenticate(userMailLogin, userMailPassword);
```

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык